# Tor Browser Automatically Sets Proxy

Tags: linux, browser, internet, proxy, tor

So, I was dumb, and used to think that the TOR browser was used to access the dark web, and acts as a place where the world's greatest hackers reside, but in reality, it's just a super secure web browser.

So, I downloaded it. However, take note that I downloaded it on a rather odd system. I am using an IBX-530, with Lubnutu installed on it. Anyways, when I tried to open the browser, I first got an error saying that the proxy server refused connections. Which is odd because I never set or enabled a proxy. So, I checked, and as it turns out, tor automatically enabled a SOCKSV5 proxy to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), at port 9150. And I'm not sure why this proxy was enabled, but it was.

I tried disabling the proxy, but it still didn't work. So then I enabled port-forwarding to port 9150, and it still didn't work. I wasn't able to find any solutions online, because it seems as if no one else is having this problem.

And keep in mind, I am new to TOR and the TOR network in general. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *bundle* of programs that are pre-configured to work together, you should just extract and run (assuming you **have a working internet connection**).

If you're messing with it's own settings, it's probably broken now.

Download a good copy and just extract & run it. Then if you still have problems that's something else.

Comment: I don't remember ever messing with any of the settings, but I did fresh re-install, and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what could've happened, maybe the proxy disable wasn't related, maybe it was just an old version you had before (they update every month or so), at any rate it's good news it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, Tor actually is a network, not just a browser. The browser you know is actually a modified version of Firefox.

Also, you might get a proxy error if you run Tor from one location on your computer then move it to another and try to run it from there. This is probably why the browser shows an error right at start.